# docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: no context set

Tags: docker

I'm trying to install the https://github.com/dani-garcia/bitwarden_rs docker container on OSX (docker installed via a brew cask).

Running:

`docker pull bitwardenrs/server:latest`

successfully pulls the image but running

`docker run -d --name bitwarden -v /bw-data/:/data/ -p 80:80 /bitwardenrs/server:latest`

results in

`docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: no context set`

I could not find any mention of that docker error anywhere

Comment: /bw-data/:/data/ it because of this, docker have permission issue with /bwdata

Comment: /bw-data/, Docker might want you to share permission for this folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! It was indeed a directory permission issue, pointing it at any shared directory fixes it, e.g.

`docker run -d --name bitwarden -v /tmp/bw-data/:/data/ -p 80:80 bitwardenrs/server`